# Creating a Maven report plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm trying to build a custom report plugin for Maven, to be used with `mvn site`.

But I can't find any updated documentation on how to proceed.

Official documentation about creating a plugin mentions extending the `org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo`. But this is about "regular" plugins for the usual build lifecycle. It's not for the `site` build lifecycle.

There is a similar question on SO ([Writing a maven custom report plugin; how do I generate the html body or "middle" of my report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394398/writing-a-maven-custom-report-plugin-how-do-i-generate-the-html-body-or-middle)) which refers to a document from 2015, which mentions the `AbstractMavenReport` class instead of the `AbstractMojo` class, but I can't find it anywhere to be imported in my project.

I also looked at the code of some recent report plugins (the `changes` plugin here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-changes-plugin-2.12.1/), but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Isn't there at least an archetype for report plugins? Anyone has experience in this?

Thank you!
-- Bertrand

Comment: There is not a lot of documentation out there. Could you tell us what kind of plugin you are trying to do? The best thing to do is what you did. Whatch the code of an existing plugin. 

If you tell us a bit about what you are trying to do we could advise about a plugin to look to watch the code.

Comment: I'm trying to build a plugin that produces a Reference Guide based on some of the source code of the project (which is written in a proprietary language of a 3rd-party editor). Something like Javadoc, but with different input and different syntax. I actually find my answer (see answer below). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more digging and I found my answer:
http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-reporting-impl/index.html

And a working example:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/shared/tags/maven-reporting-impl-3.0.0/src/it/setup-reporting-plugin/

So, basically, you'll need this in your *pom.xml*:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-reporting-impl</artifactId>
      <version>@project.version@</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-reporting-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- plugin API and plugin-tools -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shared-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And then, your main class has to extend `AbstractMavenReport`:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport;
import org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException;

/**
 * Typical code to copy as a reporting plugin start: choose the goal name, then implement getOutputName(),
 * getName( Locale ), getDescription( Locale ) and of course executeReport( Locale ).
 */
@Mojo( name = "custom" )
public class CustomReport
    extends AbstractMavenReport
{
    public String getOutputName()
    {
        return "custom-report";
    }

    public String getName( Locale locale )
    {
        return "Custom Maven Report";
    }

    public String getDescription( Locale locale )
    {
        return "Custom Maven Report Description";
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeReport( Locale locale )
        throws MavenReportException
    {
        // direct report generation using Doxia: compare with CustomReportRenderer to see the benefits of using
        // ReportRenderer
        getSink().head();
        getSink().title();
        getSink().text( "Custom Report Title" );
        getSink().title_();
        getSink().head_();

        getSink().body();

        getSink().section1();
        getSink().sectionTitle1();
        getSink().text( "section" );
        getSink().sectionTitle1_();

        getSink().text( "Custom Maven Report content." );
        getSink().section1_();

        getSink().body_();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help future developers of Maven Reporting plugins! ;-)

Comment: FYI, I just started an official Maven intro https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-report-plugin-development.html that will explain a little bit more in detail why it is like you describe. Help and feedback appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you Hervé! I think it's going to be most helpful to developers! How can we help?

Comment: if you can provide pull requests on this page, that would help me a lot

Comment: I'd happy to. But you'll have to pardon the newbie I am: I can't even find the source repo for the Web site... I only found the Jira project https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MNGSITE/ (which is a starting point, I guess), and the Fisheye repo https://fisheye.apache.org/browse/maven where I can't find the pages you are referring to (the guides). Sorry for the dummy question... :-/

Comment: No dumb question: I know Maven is a big piece of software with many parts and making clear where is what part is not easy, both from documenter and newcomer pov. On source repository page http://maven.apache.org/source-repository.html, you'll find "sources for this site": any idea on improving this page to make it easier for newcomers is also welcome (I now see there is no link to the Git mirror of the site svn repo = https://github.com/apache/maven-site )

Comment: Hi @hboutemy, 3 months later, I finally opened my [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/maven-site/pull/11) with the guide to write a report plugin. About time... ;-)